# Controllers necessáriamente precisam ser classes?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, mvc

Quando estamos desenvolvendo um sistema usando MVC desde o zero, cada controller precisa ser uma classe ou posso simplesmente usar um arquivo contendo algumas funções que serão chamadas conforme a action enviada pela View?

Exemplo, tenho um controler para a view "perfil" que apresenta os dados do usuário e atualiza eles caso necessário.

```
include_once('model/usuario.php');
class Controller{
  public $dadosUser;

  function __construct($action = null){
    if(empty($action)){
        $user = new Usuario();
        $id = $user->id;
        $this->dadosUser =  $user->loadUsr($id);
     }
  }
}
```

Nesse caso, é possivel alterar o valor da $action quando for instanciar um novo Controller?

Outro exemplo é um arquivo genérico que estou implementando da seguinte forma:

```
 include_once('../model/usuario.php');

 $action = isset($_POST['action']) ? $_POST['action'] : "";

 if($action){
  switch($action){
    case 'login':login(); break;
    case 'listar':getAllAqr();break;
    default: break;
  }
 }

 function login(){
   $email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : "";
   $pwd = isset($_POST['senha']) ? $_POST['senha'] : "";

   $usr = new Usuario();
   $usr->login($email, $pwd);

   $id = $usr->id;
   if($id){
    header("Location: http://localhost/aldeia/dashboard.php");
   }else
    header("Location: http://localhost/aldeia/login.php");
 }
```

Qual dessas duas formas é a mais adequada?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O ideal é sempre usar classes, isso vai facilitar muito a sua vida. 
Aconselho também a deixar o gerenciamento dos includes de forma automática, se não for usar  nenhum framework e for fazer tudo na unha invista um pouco de tempo estudando o http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php, acredito que isso já irá te motivar a usar classes. Sobre fazer um controle genérico mudando os dados no construtor, verifique se em vez disso não lhe atende mais criar uma classe abstrata e usar o conceito de herança e polimorfismo para atender melhor suas necessidades.

[Nesse link você pode encontrar mais conceitos de orientação a objeto em php](http://www.petsi.facom.ufu.br/system/files/Minicurso%20PHP.pdf) 
[Nesse link você pode encontrar mais conceitos de MVC](http://w3.ufsm.br/pet-cc/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Apresenta%C3%A7%C3%A3o-MVC.pdf)
[Uma outra sugestão seria o uso de namespace](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/br/library/os-php-5.3namespaces/)

O MVC contudo não obriga que use Classes, O conceito de MVC pode ser aplicado até em linguagens que não são Orientada a Objetos, mas o PHP permite a Orientação a Objetos, com base nisso: Entre as opções apresentas eu escolheria a primeira como a mais adequada entre as duas.